# Print while cv2.imshow() for a period of time

Tags: python, opencv, imshow, imread

I've been trying to do a simple task, but unfortunately I'm not able to get it work, I'm starting to think that this can not be done, but since it's too simple I may be the silliest guy:

What I want to do is to print some values over a period of time while showing an Image, so if I increase the period of time I will get more values printed.

I've tried with while loops, if conditions, and definitions.

here is an example:

```
    cpt = 0
    IAPS_img = "./IAPS_Images/"

    image = cv2.imread(IAPS_img + "cat.jpg")
    while(True):            
        cv2.imshow('image',image) 
        cpt += 1
        print(cpt)  
        while(True):
            k = cv2.waitKey(3000)
            if k == 27:
   break
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can execute succesfully in cmd using the following comands:

```
    cd... python script1.py &
    cd... python script2.py &
```

but not able in a single script, I'm doing this because instead of printing some numbers I want to take some photos, if I get this done I may be able to do it the way I wanted.

I'm open for suggestions:

> P.D. I'm doing this because I'm not able to get this done in CMD >>>>>> "instead of printing some numbers I want to take some photos at the same time I'm showing an image.

Thank you,

Comment: You want the windows to be destroyed after the given time period without hitting any key from keyboard, right?

Comment: That is exactly what I want sir, I used the library time.sleep() too, but it prints the values every n seconds and then destroys the window

Comment: Instead of using `while(True)`, can't you calculate current time and at your delay at that time, Then put those condition in `while()`. For e.g. `currentTimeMin = 23`, suppose you want image to be opened for `1 minute` then add `destroyTime = currentTimeMin+1`, and put these to in while like `while(destroyTime != currentTimeMin)` and keep getting `currentTimeMin` inside while!

Comment: If the printing is unrelated to the displaying, I would suggest you use multiprocessing to run the displaying in one process and the printing in another - it makes life simpler.

Comment: I ended using multiprocessing.I do not how I did not noticed that, thanks @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your while loop so that it only runs for a set period of time. You can try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = datetime.now()
cpt = 0
IAPS_img = "./IAPS_Images/"

image = cv2.imread(IAPS_img + "cat.jpg")
while datetime.now() - start < timedelta(seconds=5*60*60):        
    cv2.imshow('image',image) 
    cpt += 1
    print(cpt)  
    while(True):
        k = cv2.waitKey(3000)
        if k == 27:
break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: following to this answer. I could not get it work. it only prints one **cpt (counter)**. When I use `while():` instead of `while(True):` , it increments the cpt, but for some reason the image doesn't get destroy. _Multithreading_ solves this problem, but it doesn't let me kill the thread outsite of loop when I want to (I want to take pictures while image is display). I read about **multiprocessing** but it doesn't support  anaconda, and couldn't get it work in python 3 IDLE. So I look forward for an alternative solution, I've past so much time in this...